# How to extract top 10 values from data set, when there are duplicates

Tags: excel

I am pulling data from a data source and want to rank the top 10 values from this data source and return the fruit name. In my photo I only have 5, but in my actual data set there are thousands. The way I’m doing it now is using Large on the data set to pull the top 10 values, however, because there are duplicate values (such as price) it ends up returning the first fruit with that value each time when you do an Index Match.[image]

Comment: The Large of **what**? Your data doesn't support your narrative. Where is your current Large formula?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in cols **A** and **B** like:

[image]

We will use a "helper" column to avoid array formulas.  So in **F2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(E2,B:B,0),"")
```

in **F3** enter:

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF($E$1:$E3,E3)>1,MATCH(E3,INDIRECT("$B" & F2+1 & ":B9999" ),0)+F2,MATCH(E3,B:B,0)),"")
```

and copy downwards.

Column **F** gives us row information.

in **D2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,F2),"")
```

and copy downward.  In **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(B:B,ROW()-1),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]